# How to check against all items in an array even if some items are empty?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects. The array gets a value based on its index position. Sometimes the array will only have a value at a certain index like so

```
array = [], //initial value
array[1] = {name: 'John Doe', address: '123 Main St', registered: true}
```

I simply want to set a variable to true/false, if a predicate function finds a value present in any of the items.

```
var hasValue = array.find(personObj => !!personObj.registered)
```

**The Problem:**

The above function will always return false if the 0 index position is empty.The predicate function never runs past the 0 indexed position if its empty. Here is an image that better describes the structure:

[image]

**The Question:**

How can I properly check all items in an array even if some items are empty?

Comment: `array.find(personObj => !!personObj.registered)` This will break at `0` with `register of undefined`

Comment: This is a bit of an X/Y problem - better to not have sparse arrays in the first place, they're horrible. Use an object instead.

Comment: Looks like you could be using an object instead of an array for that use case...

Comment: Setting objects at a given index correlate to a certain ID, so I really can't restructure it...I hear you guys

Comment: Why don't you just start your array at index 0?

Comment: because each index item is associated with an id of a unique person object

Comment: find() method returns the value of the first element in an array that pass a test so i think you need to use every() method, array.every(personObj => personObj && !!personObj.registered);

Comment: Then put that id/index _into_ your object, `{id: 1, name: 'John Doe', address: '123 Main St', registered: true}`

Comment: the question is still a bit unclear, what you want. do you like to visit each object and check a value, do you like to get the first wone with a `true` property, or do you like to find missing indices, or just the irst empty?

Comment: @NinaScholz Please honor us with properly formatted text, where e.g. a sentence starts with a capital letter. It will make it easier to read.

Comment: sorry, no caps.

Comment: first one with a true property is all i care about

Comment: Then you need to update the question, as it asks "How can I properly check **all** items in an array even if some items are empty?"

Comment: Thats already implied with the find method i'm using, it's not wrong it its wording. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check if the object exists.

[`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

> `callback` is invoked for *every* index of the array, not just those with assigned values. This means it may be less efficient for sparse arrays, compared to methods that only visit assigned values.

```js
var array = [];

array[1] = { name: 'John Doe', address: '123 Main St', registered: true };

var hasValue = array.find(personObj => personObj && !!personObj.registered)

console.log(hasValue);
```